# How send list over asyncio socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, client-server, python-asyncio

I can easly send messages from my server to one connected client, you can see it in my code `writer.write(("you write: ").encode('utf8') + response.encode('utf8'))`

But how for example send a list/array/matrix over asyncio sockets? in the bellow example, how send the `hi` list to one connected client... I try just  `writer.write(hi.encode('utf8'))` but its not work !

```
import asyncio

hi=[1, 2, 3, 4]

@asyncio.coroutine
def handle_client(reader, writer):
    request = None
    response = ""
    word=""

    while word != 'quit' and request != b'':
        request = (yield from reader.read(255))

        if str(b'\r\n') == str((request)[-2:]) and len(request) > 2:
            response=str((request.decode('utf8'))).rstrip()
            request=str(b'\r\n')

        if str(b'\r\n') == str(request):
            word=response
            response = response + str('\n\r')
            writer.write(("you write: ").encode('utf8') + response.encode('utf8'))
            response =""
            addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
            print("I get: " + word)
            print(addr)
            
        else:
            response = response + str((request.decode('utf8')))



        yield from writer.drain()
    
    writer.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.create_task(asyncio.start_server(handle_client, '127.0.0.1', 4312))
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: You can’t send arbitrary objects through the socket, only bytes. You’ll need to serialize your list into a format that will need to be deserialized on the other end. Also, you probably don’t need any of those `str` calls and they’re probably doing you more harm than good (e.g., `str(b”a”)` is `”b’a’”`).

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but it is recommend to avoid the `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator and `yield from` in new code, as they are [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#generator-based-coroutines) since Python 3.8 and announced to be removed in Python 3.10. Define an `async def` instead and use `await`, both have been available since Python 3.5 (released in 2015).

Answer (score 1):

In the provided example `hi` is a list type object, as such it does not have an `encode()` method. Also writer is an [asyncio.StreamWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamWriter) type object, whose `write()` method expects a `bytes` type object. What this means is that the object -> bytes encoding has to be handled by the caller of `write()` method. Also the receiver of the data has to do the bytes -> list decoding on their end.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your immediate question, you'll need to serialize the data in a way both ends of the communication agree on and understand. Couple options could be for instance:

- JSON:

  ```
  import json
  json.dumps(hi).encode("utf8")
  ```

  To get `bytes` you can send over and receive it with:

  ```
  received = json.loads(response)
  ```

  This seems perfectly adequate for your example and does have an advantage of the data being passed around being also readable to a human being.
- pickle:

  ```
  import pickle
  pickle.dumps(hi)
  ```

  This also produces `bytes` you can de-serialize on the receiving end:

  ```
  received = pickle.loads(response)
  ```

  This has an advantage of being more general method which could also be used for types you could not serialize with JSON.